# How to correctly use constructors?

Tags: java, constructor

Hi I am new to Java and constructors are still consfusing me. I am trying to create and enum as below:

```
public enum SCardErrors
{
    SCARD_S_SUCCESS(0x0L),
    SCARD_E_SHARING_VIOLATION(0x8010000BL),
    SCARD_E_NO_READERS_AVAILABLE(0x8010002EL),
    SCARD_E_READER_UNAVAILABLE(0x80100017L);

    private int intValue;
    private static java.util.HashMap<Integer, SCardErrors> mappings;
    private static java.util.HashMap<Integer, SCardErrors> getMappings()
    {
        if (mappings == null)
        {
            synchronized (SCardErrors.class)
            {
                if (mappings == null)
                {
                    mappings = new java.util.HashMap<Integer, SCardErrors>();
                }
            }
        }
        return mappings;
    }

    private SCardErrors(int value)
    {
        intValue = value;
        getMappings().put(value, this);
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return intValue;
    }

    public static SCardErrors forValue(int value)
    {
        return getMappings().get(value);
    }
}
```

From above it gives the error that constructor SCardErrors(long) is undefined for the lines:
    SCARD_S_SUCCESS(0x0L),
    SCARD_E_SHARING_VIOLATION(0x8010000BL),
    SCARD_E_NO_READERS_AVAILABLE(0x8010002EL),
    SCARD_E_READER_UNAVAILABLE(0x80100017L);

I have tried adding in 
    SCARD_S_SUCCESS(0x0L){
                       }
for each of them but it did not fix the error. I also tried adding them as a parameter but this didn't work. Can someone please help??

Answer (score 2):

You've only got a constructor accepting `int`:

```
private SCardErrors(int value)
```

... but you're trying to call it with an argument of type `long`:

```
SCARD_S_SUCCESS(0x0L)
```

You either need to change the constructor to accept a `long` - and probably change the field type as well - or change the arguments to be `int` values instead. Not all of your arguments can be represented as `int` (e.g. 0x80100017L) - but if you only care about the bits involved, and don't mind the values becoming negative, you could cast to `int` and still have the same 32 bits...

Answer (score 1):

The reason Java does not find the constructor is that you used `L` suffix on all your numeric literals, making them `long`, not `int`. Java does not allow conversion of `long` to `int` without an explicit cast, so the compiler cannot apply the constructor that takes an `int` in this situation (the other way around, i.e. passing an `int` to a method or a constructor expecting a `long`, would have worked).

You can fix this by changing the compiler to take `long`, and using `longValue` in place of `intValue`:

```
private long longValue;
private static java.util.HashMap<Long, SCardErrors> mappings;
private static java.util.HashMap<Long, SCardErrors> getMappings()
{
    if (mappings == null)
    {
        synchronized (SCardErrors.class)
        {
            if (mappings == null)
            {
                mappings = new java.util.HashMap<Long, SCardErrors>();
            }
        }
    }
    return mappings;
}

private SCardErrors(long value)
{
    longValue = value;
    getMappings().put(value, this);
}

public long getValue()
{
    return longValue;
}

public static SCardErrors forValue(long value)
{
    return getMappings().get(value);
}
```